# How can I update GUI from a DLL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dll

I would like to make a plugin system. I already made a plugin loader (from MSDN tutorial) which loads every DLL in a directory and calls functions from it. I also give my WPF window as an argument.

In the "Demo" plugin, I add as a reference my executable, so that I can access the window class (when I copy the demoplugin.dll, I don't copy the references -dll and exe- because it's already loaded by the main project).
Fact is I can access my custom functions & variables, but not the "Title", etc. I guess it's because the DLL does not run in the GUI thread, and I know I can use callbacks or `BackgroundWorker`, but that's for specific tasks. I don't want to make a callback for all methods and properties of every element on my form.

What can I do?

Comment: [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) can help you.

Comment: Not sure I understand how this can help, because this is on the project side, and when I'll open the dll project, VS won't see the SynchronizationContext, and will not compile..

Comment: What do you mean? Am not sure I understand your comment. Why `SynchronizationContext` wont compile? I have used it in a dll. Note that `SynchronizationContext` class is in mscorlib.dll. Please clarify if you mean something else

Comment: I was not understanding how SynchronizationContext was working. I do now, and this absolutly solve my problem. Thanks !